# Making a parallel polygon at a certain distance

Tags: 3d, geometry

I have a set of points in 3d space, which is given by x, y and z coordinates. This set of points is in one plane (which can be at some angle) and forms a polygon. I need to build the same polygon, parallel to this one, at a certain distance. How can I calculate delta x, delta y, delta z for parallel polygon points?

Edited: Lines A to A1, B to B1, etc. are perpendicular to the base polygon

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 1):

You need the direction normal to the plane. Then multiply the direction with the length to get the vector displacement.

1. Take three points of the polygon **A**, **B**, and **C** that are not colinear and calculate the normal direction

   ```
   normal = cross(A,B) + cross(B,C) + cross(C,A)
   normal = normal/mangitude(normal)
   ```
2. Find the displacement vector **u** such that `A1 = A + u`, `B1 = B + u`, etc

   ```
   u = length * normal
   ```
3. Loop to find new coordinates

   ```
   for i=1 to n
       P1(i) = P(i) + u
   next i
   ```

I assume the environment you are coding in allows for basic linear algebra, such as adding and scaling vectors.

Comment: To elaborate on your answer : to check that A, B and C are not colinear, you can use scalar product : |AB.AC| = ||AB||.||AC||.cos(angle(AB, AC)) so  "A,B, C are colinear" is equivalent to, "|AB.AC| = ||AB||.||AC||"

Comment: @PierreBaret - If they are colinear then `cross(A,B) + cross(B,C) + cross(C,A)` would be a (near) zero vector. Remember the vector cross product `A×B = cross(A,B)` returns zero for parallel vectors. There is no need for additional computations, and certainly not ones requiring taking so many vector norms.

Answer (score 0):

```
    val deltaX = length * base.a / (base.a + base.b + base.c)
    val deltaY = length * base.b / (base.a + base.b + base.c)
    val deltaZ = length * base.c / (base.a + base.b + base.c)
```

Where a, b and c are the factors of the base plane equation.
Further, if we add the delta coordinates to the initial ones, we get the desired values of the coordinates of the points.

Answer (score 0):

```
 deltaX = normal.x * distance / Length(normal)
 similar for y,z
```

where `normal` is normal vector to the plane (your `a,b,c` from plane equation are corresponding components of this vector)

```
Length(normal) = sqrt(normal.x^2 + normal.y^2 + normal.z^2)
```

Often normal is unit vector, in this case denominator is not needed